# How can I set an increasing variable using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

All I need is this:

```
serial_number | id    | idu
----------------------------
1             |  1    |  1
2             |  5    |  8
3             |  9    |  1
4             |  15   |  13
5             |  23   |  1
6             |  34   |  1
7             |  58   |  5
```

`serial_number` is a column generated with an increasing number by one (from 1 to max rows).

I tried this query:

```
SELECT @s := @s +1 serial_number, t.id 
FROM tracks AS t , (SELECT @s :=0) AS s 
JOIN users AS u ON (u.idu = t.uid);
```

What's wrong in my query?

Comment: Without an order by clause, this is rather indeterminate

Comment: You've lost me.

Comment: @Strawberry based on this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html I set my `$primaryKey = 'id';` so the `order by` is not needed

Comment: The ORDER BY is ALWAYS needed: http://rextester.com/FECNPZ40895

Comment: As an aside, I think you're going to find the interchangeability of uid and idu maddeningly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT (@s := @s + 1) as serial_number, t.id 
FROM tracks t JOIN
     users u
     ON u.idu = t.uid CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @s := 0) params ;
```

The problem with your query is that you are mixing old-style joins and proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The simple solution is to follow the rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

The specific problem that you have is a scoping problem.  The `t` alias is not known in the `ON` clause because the scope is not known after the comma.  Hence, "comma" and `CROSS JOIN` are not exactly the same thing due to scoping differences.

If you want the values in a particular order, you can add an `order by` clause.  However, your question does not suggest that any particular ordering is desired.

Comment: You're missing an ORDER BY clause

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Read the question.  If you see any reference to the ordering of the rows, I would be intrigued to know how you came up with it.  The "increasing number" is the `serial_number`.

Comment: It increases according to id

Comment: @Strawberry . . . The OP does not even hint that that is a requirement.

Comment: In which case, the correct query would be ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: The OP believes (erroneously) that the presence of a PK is sufficient to guarantee the ordering of rows. That is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is a column that automatically increments. If so, then the easiest way would be to set a dedicated column as both `primary key` and `auto increment`. These are both achievable when you create/alter your table.